# OpenLayers text layer not working

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to load markers from a text file using OpenLayers text layer, but no marker is shown, text file and icons are in same directory. However I am able to show markers using marker layer. My code is here and text file is also attached.

```
function init()
{   
 /*
Create a new Map with Basic controls which are passed as
arguments
*/
var map= new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',
{
    controls:[
    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
    new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
    //new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution()
    ],
    numZoomLevels:19,
    units:'m'
}
);

 // default lan/lat projection in which points will be provided
 var epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    /* 
Create Basic Layers to show on map
*/
// openstreetmap layer
var osm_map_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM (
'Open Street Maps'
);
// google map layer
var google_map_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
'Google Street Maps',
{sphericalMercator: true,
maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
-20037508.34,-20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34)}
);

/*
vector layer to draw custom shapes on map
*/
var vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors");
/*
markers layer will be used to insert markers on map
*/
var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers");
    /* 
layers are added to map
*/
pois = new OpenLayers.Layer.Text( "My points", { location:"./pois.txt", projection:     map.displayProjection});
map.addLayer(pois);
map.addLayers(
[
osm_map_layer,
//google_map_layer,
//vectors,
markers,
pois
]
);  
//

var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(48.9459301,9.6075669);
lonlat.transform(epsg4326, map.getProjectionObject());
map.setCenter(lonlat, 15);
markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat));



} // last closing bracket
```

and text file

lat lon title   description icon    iconSize

iconOffset
48.9459301  9.6075669   Title One   Description

one
Second line.
(click again to close)

Ol_icon_blue_example.png    24,24   0,-24
48.9899851  9.5382032   Title Two   Description

two.    Ol_icon_red_example.png 16,16   -8,-8

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem like you! You should write your data in each rows with spacing between columns by Tabs.. and also, it is important that fill the last row by spaces as strings and tabs.. it should be work!